# Obtener fecha y hora actual con un retardo de un minuto JAVA

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch

Estoy desarrollando una función para consultar a ElasticSearch un cambio de contraseña en una aplicación.

La consola de Elastic me muestra cada RESET_PASSWORD que he realizado sobre un usuario en concreto pero necesito siempre la más reciente en fecha.Actualmente le estoy pasando una fecha fija para hacer las pruebas pero no se como pasarle la fecha mas actual del cambio..He pensado en usar la fecha de hoy menos unos segundos ya que la consulta la hago segundos despues pero no encuentro en la web nada fiable.

Datos usuario en Elastic:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La query que declaro es:

```
String elasticSearchTSQuery =  "{\"size\": "+size+", \"from\": fromValue, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"range\":{\"date\":{\"gt\": ?}}},{\"match\":{\"operation\":\"RESET_PASSWORD\"}},{\"match\":{\"managedSystemId\":\"2c9c8e176c4cca39016c6c8c10960216\"}},{\"match\":{\"targetIdentity\":"+user.getNickname()+"}}]}}}";
```

Ahora mismo estoy usando `SimpleDateFormat` y lo reemplazo en la query pero solo me saca desde la fecha en adelante :

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
    String lastIndexDateAsStr = "01/09/2020 13:00:00.000";
    lastExecTime = df.parse(lastIndexDateAsStr).getTime();
    elasticSearchTSQuery = elasticSearchTSQuery.replaceAll("\\?", Long.toString(lastExecTime));
```

Answer (score 2):

Se que no es lo que estás preguntando directamente pero puedes sacar el documento más reciente de Elastic de esta forma

```
{
  "query": {
    // aquí iría lo que quieres filtrar. sea nickname o whatever
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`_timestamp` es una columna que puedes [activar en el mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) para que se actualize automáticamente y no necesitar guardar el `date` pero sino puedes usar el `date` que ya tienes.

Por otro lado te recomendaría usar el cliente HighLevel de Elastic para java [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html) y te hará la vida mas fácil en vez de trabajar con strings como estás haciendo.

Y finalmente, como veo que esas fechas parece estar en milisegundos

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - 10_000 // ahora - 10 seconds
```

Comment: Voy a probar lo de HighLevel,es cierto que Elastic no lo he manejado nunca pero parece intuitivo y fácil,muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para ello tenemos la clase Java Calendar. Lo primero que tenemos que saber de la clase Calendar es la forma de instanciarlo. Y es que no podemos instanciar directamente una clase Calendar. Es decir, no podemos hacer un new Calendar(). Lo que podemos hacer son dos cosas: o bien utilizamos el método estático .getInstance() de la clase Calendar, o bien, construimos una clase GregorianCalendar.

En ambos casos lo que obtenemos es una clase Calendar la cual contiene información de la fecha local del sistema. Y es que la clase Calendar nos permite otras cosas, como por ejemplo, obtener la fecha de otra ubicación geográfica que no sea la del sistema.

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar();
```

na vez que tenemos instanciada nuestra clase Calendar ya podremos hacer uso de los «getters» y «setters» de antaño. Pero con una modificación y es que existe un único método get que recibe por parámetro el tipo de información a recuperar en formato número entero. Si bien, no tenemos que sabernos la correspondencia de valores de los números enteros, ya que la clase Calendar nos ofrece un conjunto de clases estáticas para facilitarnos la ayuda.

Relativo a estas constantes tenemos:

`Calendar.DATE`, que representa el día del mes.
`Calendar.MONTH`, que representa el mes del año.
`Calendar.YEAR`, que representa el año.
Tenemos muchas otras más `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, DAY_OF_WEEK, WEEK_OF_YEAR,…`

Al final, nuestro código Java quedará algo así:

```
dia = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
mes = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
annio = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Ahora adapta este ejemplo espero haberte ayudado